# Apple Mach-O Linker Error (5)

Tags: ios, xcode, mach-o

Whenever I try to build my project (it has both [IFUnicodeURL](https://github.com/BigZaphod/IFUnicodeURL) and [JSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework)), I keep getting these 5 Mach-O errors.

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

```
  "_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from:
      -[NSString(NPMimeType) mimeType] in NSString+NPMimeType.o
  "_UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from:
      -[NSString(NPMimeType) mimeType] in NSString+NPMimeType.o
  "_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from:
      -[NSString(NPMimeType) mimeType] in NSString+NPMimeType.o
  "_kUTTagClassFilenameExtension", referenced from:
      -[NSString(NPMimeType) mimeType] in NSString+NPMimeType.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know how to read these things and it's driving me crazy. Could anybody please help me? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using [the CloudApp Framework](https://github.com/cloudapp/objective-c/tree/master/Source/libCloud/Cloud/Categories), would you?

Comment: Yes I am, and those files are in the project too. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`